# r gplot themes -- I would like to determine colors used

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

This seems like an easy question, but I cannot find the answer.

I am using the theme_fivethirtyeight theme to do a three factor scatterplot. In ggplot2, if that makes a difference. (Although the issue would be for any theme.) I would like to capture the three colors that are used in the theme for use elsewhere.  How can I extract them from the theme?

I have seen the follow suggested:

```
library(ggthemes)
ggthemes_data$fivethirtyeight
```

But the colors listed do not seem to correspond to the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can get the hex codes of the colors:
(the codes are the same that you get from the command you posted though)

```
library("scales")
library("ggthemes")
show_col(fivethirtyeight_pal()(3))
```

[image]